# TextFlow in TableCell has an extra height

Tags: java, javafx, groovy

I tried to display rich texts in cells of TableView, and I created my own subclass of TableCell and set a TextFlow object as a graphic. But the TextFlow has an extra height like this (TextFlow is in the right column):
[image: TextFlow has an extra height]
Why does it happen?

The code is following (I wrote it in Groovy but it is almost the same as in Java):

```
public class ContentCell extends TableCell<Word, WordContent> {

  protected void updateItem(WordContent wordContent, boolean isEmpty) {
    super.updateItem(wordContent, isEmpty)
    if (isEmpty || wordContent == null) {
      setText(null)
      setGraphic(null)
    } else {
      TextFlow textFlow = wordContent.getContentTextFlow()
      setText(null)
      setGraphic(textFlow)
    }
  }

}

public class DictionaryController implements Initializable {

  @FXML private TableView<Word> wordTableView
  @FXML private TableColumn<Word, String> nameColumn
  @FXML private TableColumn<Word, WordContent> contentColumn

  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    contentColumn.setCellFactory() { TableColumn<Word, WordContent> column ->
      return new ContentCell()
    }
    for (int i : 0 ..< 50) {
      WordContent wordContent = new WordContent("test")
      Word word = new Word("test" + i.toString(), wordContent)
      wordTableView.getItems().add(word)
    }
  }

}

public class WordContent {

  private TextFlow contentTextFlow = new TextFlow()

  public WordContent(String content) {
    createContentTextFlow(content)
  }

  private void createContentTextFlow(String content) {
    Text contentText = new Text(content)
    contentTextFlow.getChildren().addAll(contentText)
  }

  public TextFlow getContentTextFlow() {
    return contentTextFlow
  }

}

public class Word {

  private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty()
  private ObjectProperty<WordContent> content = new SimpleObjectProperty()

  public Word(String name, WordContent content) {
    this.name.set(name)
    this.content.set(content)
  }

  public StringProperty nameProperty() {
    return name
  }

  public ObjectProperty<WordContent> contentProperty() {
    return content
  }

}
```

Comment: A solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855724/textflow-inside-tablecell-not-correct-cell-height/47832905#47832905

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why column height is not calculate correctly? But you can resolve the problem if you replace `TextFlow` by `FlowPane`.

If you want to wrap text, you must replace this code

```
private void createContentTextFlow(String content) {
Text contentText = new Text(content)
contentTextFlow.getChildren().addAll(contentText)
}
```

by

```
private void createContentTextFlow(String content) {
Text contentText = new Text(content)
contentText.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(#your_column_object#.widthProperty().subtract(5))
contentTextFlow.getChildren().addAll(contentText)
}
```